# Train scikit SVM, customize score assessment

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I plan on using scikit svm for class prediction.
I have a two-class dataset consisting of about 100 experiments. Each experiment encapsulates my data-points (vectors) + classification.
Training of an SVM according to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html should straight forward. 
I will have to put all vectors in an array and generate another array with the corresponding class labels, train SVM. However, in order to run leave-one-out error estimation, I need to leave out a specific subset of vectors - one experiment. 
How do I achieve that with the available score function?

Cheers,
EL

Answer (score 5):

You could manually train on everything but the one observation, using numpy indexing to drop it out. Then you can use [any of sklearn's helpers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics) to evaluate the classification. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

clf = svm.SVC(...)
idx = np.arange(len(observations))
preds = np.zeros(len(observations))
for i in idx:
    is_train = idx != i
    clf.fit(observations[is_train, :], labels[is_train])
    preds[i] = clf.predict(observations[i, :])
```

Alternatively, scikit-learn has [a helper to do leave-one-out](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut), and [another helper to get cross-validation scores](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut):

```
from sklearn import svm, cross_validation
clf = svm.SVC(...)
loo = cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(len(observations))
was_right = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, observations, labels, cv=loo)
total_acc = np.mean(was_right)
```

See [the user's guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut) for more. `cross_val_score` actually returns a score for each fold (which is a little strange IMO), but since we have one fold per observation, this will just be 0 if it was wrong and 1 if it was right.

Of course, leave-one-out is very slow and has terrible statistical properties to boot, so you should probably use [`KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html) instead.

Comment: @larsmans Nothing's necessarily that strange, just that I typically get a full vector of predictions using CV and then compute the accuracy/confusion matrix/whatever on that full prediction. Just a slightly different way of doing it.